# How do I make a Windows 7 USB bootable key using os x so I can repair a seperate Windows laptop?

Tags: windows, usb

I have a Mac. And a windows 7 laptop... I know, but it was cheap, and I needed it. The windows kernel was somehow deleted. I have a copy of win 7 on my Mac that I would like to make a bootable usb key without installing win7 to the Mac. Every thread I seem to read is directed at installing win 7 to Mac. This is something I don't wish at all. How do I make a usb bootable with windows from a Mac?

Comment: Very similar to http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/21011/how-to-create-a-windows-7-installation-usb-from-os-x but perhaps the answer there relying on BootCamp isn't a perfect fit?