# How to use UNetbootin properly?

Tags: startup, windows

Yesterday, I created a bootable USB using UNetbootin. I created it with Windows7.iso file. It was successful.

The problem is when I booted my USB onto computer, it just show me this window without proceeding to Windows 7 installation.

[image]

After that, I pressed Tab key. Then this screen appeared :

[image]

To be honest, I didn't got any ideas what to do. Is there any commands to run in this window ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is not about Apple hardware, software, or services as defined in the [Help Center](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help)

Comment: @Allan I disagree. He's using macOS to create the installer, so–if it turns out that is the issue–it is about software running on Apple hardware. There's a precedent for installer questions being allowed (see [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/103874/creating-a-bootable-usb-of-windows-8-1-on-os-x/103879#103879) and [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/123570/create-a-bootable-windows-usb-from-a-os-x-to-work-on-a-pc).) However, it's also possible that this isn't on the macOS end–but we don't know. I'd rather let it stew and see if someone knows the answer than close.

Answer (score 0):

Unetbootin wasn't designed with Windows in mind, and while it does support it, it doesn't install necessary drivers required by Apple laptops for Windows by default. It's highly recommended to use [Boot Camp](https://support.apple.com/boot-camp) instead.

> 1. Start up your Mac in macOS.
> 2. Use the compatibility tables to make sure you have a Mac that supports the version of Windows you're installing.
> 3. If your copy of Windows came on a DVD, you might need to create a disk image of it to work with Boot Camp.
> 4. Connect a 16GB or larger USB flash drive that you can erase. Leave this flash drive connected to your Mac until Windows installation is
>      finished.
> 5. Open Boot Camp Assistant from the Utilities folder (or use Spotlight to find it) and click Continue.
> 6. Select only the options to create a Windows install disk and to download the latest Windows support software from Apple. Then click
>      Continue.
> 7. Insert your Windows install disc if you haven't done so already, or choose your Windows installation ISO, then click Continue. Boot Camp
>      erases your USB flash drive and prepares it for Windows installation.
>      When you see "Download Support Software for Windows 7", close the Boot
>      Camp Assistant window to quit the app.
> 8. Use the compatibility tables to find the Windows support software (drivers) you need for the version of Windows and the Mac that you're
>      using.
> 9. Click the link in the table to download the related software.
> 10. After the file downloads, double-click it from the Finder to decompress (unzip) it.
> 11. Open the resulting folder. Locate the following files in this folder and drag them to your USB Flash drive. When prompted if you
>       want to replace the existing items on the flash drive, click Yes:
>
> $WinPEDriver$ (folder) AutoUnattend.xml BootCamp (folder)
>
> 12. Open Boot Camp Assistant again, then click Continue.
> 13. Select only the option to "Install Windows… or later version."
> 14. Click Install, then follow the onscreen prompts to repartition your drive and install Windows.
> 15. When you complete the assistant, your Mac restarts to the Windows installer. When you're asked where you want to install Windows, select
>       the BOOTCAMP partition, then click Drive Options and format your Boot
>       Camp partition.
> 16. Follow the onscreen prompts to finish installing Windows

Though there are other methods of installing Windows (including using Unetbootin), they're far more complicated and prone to failure. I strongly recommend using Boot Camp.

Comment: I didn't want to install Windows on my Mac laptop. I just want to create a bootable usb though.

Comment: Ah, I see. In that case, [this is a duplicate](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/103874/creating-a-bootable-usb-of-windows-8-1-on-os-x/103879#103879). You could also try [Etcher](https://etcher.io), but it doesn't guarantee it'll work for Windows ISOs.